# Rails 4, nested association search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, where-clause

I have the following associations.

```
class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :crops
end

class Crop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :farm
    has_many :seed_batches
end

class SeedBatch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :crop
    has_many :tasks, through: :task_batches
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :seed_batches, through: :task_batches
end

class TaskBatch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :seed_batch
end
```

In essence, a farm has many crops. each crop has many seed batches. each seed batch has many tasks.

My question is this: How can i get all the tasks knowing the id of a farm?

I have tried many ways to do .where() searches, but all came up to errors. Can anyone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  Farm.find(1).crops.each(&:seed_batches).collect(&:tasks)
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! Wow. All the while I had been thinking from Task, how do i find out if they belong to the same farm. But I totally didn't see it from the other way round! Perspective...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define `has_many :tasks` for Crop and Farm:

```
class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :crops
    has_many :tasks, through: :crops
end

class Crop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :farm
    has_many :seed_batches
    has_many :tasks, through: :seed_batches
end
```

Then you should be able to access all tasks with `Farm.find(id).tasks`